# Reading raster files by block with rasterio?

Tags: python, raster, gdal, rasterio

I find [rasterio](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio) much easier to use that [plain ogr/gdal](http://www.gis.usu.edu/~chrisg/python/2009/), so I'd prefer using it. However, I need to process large rasters, so reading rasters by block as explained in the [Python GDAL course](http://www.gis.usu.edu/~chrisg/python/2009/lectures/ospy_slides4.pdf) is important for me.

Does rasterio support this or should I handle the large, tilable rasters with GDAL instead?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Reading Rasters by block can be done in rasterio and I'd argue it's easier than in GDAL. There is even a [tutorial on windowed read/write](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/blob/master/docs/topics/windowed-rw.rst) over at GitHub.

Let's take a look at the `read` functions arguments, which allows you to set a window to read data from:

```
def read(self, indexes=None, out=None, window=None, masked=False,
        boundless=False):
"""Read raster bands as a multidimensional array
    Parameters
    ----------
    window : a pair (tuple) of pairs of ints, optional
        The optional `window` argument is a 2 item tuple. The first
        item is a tuple containing the indexes of the rows at which
        the window starts and stops and the second is a tuple
        containing the indexes of the columns at which the window
        starts and stops. For example, ((0, 2), (0, 2)) defines
        a 2x2 window at the upper left of the raster dataset.
"""
```

So all you need now is a way to create the window tuples. That's what rasterios `block_windows` function is for:

```
def block_windows(self, bidx=0):
    """Returns an iterator over a band's block windows and their
    indexes.
    [....]
    The primary use of this function is to obtain windows to pass to
    read_band() for highly efficient access to raster block data.
    """
```

So in your case I guess the code would look something like this:

```
with rasterio.open("your/data/geo.tif") as src:
     for block_index, window in src.block_windows(1):
         block_array = src.read(window=window)
         result_block = some_calculation(block_array)
```

Comment: How do you then reassemble `result_block` into a full result array with the same dimensions as `src`?

Comment: How would I do something similar in R? I have a very big (in terms of pixels) raster that I want to divide into blocks and iterate through the blocks to do my analysis.

Comment: @tg110 that might be better suited as its own question.