# Segmentation fault while writing an output raster by blocks with rasterio

Tags: python, raster, numpy, rasterio

With the answer on [my previous question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/158527/12768), I was able to set up reading a raster by blocks. I did some computation and now I try to write the result into another raster. However, the program fails with error code 139 and `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. My code:

```
with rasterio.drivers():
    with rasterio.open(asterPath,'r') as src:
        with rasterio.open(ndviPath,'w',driver='GTiff', width=src.shape[0], height=src.shape[1], count=1, dtype=np.float32) as dst:
            for index, window in src.block_windows(2):
                red = src.read(2, window=window)
                nir = src.read(3, window=window)
                #compute ndvi as NumPy 2d array, dtype float32
                dst.write_band(1,ndvi,window=window)
```

As a sanity check, I tried to fill ndvi array with zeros. It worked outside the loop, but not within, so I must have misunderstood something about writing by block with rasterio. All I know about rasterio is [this manual](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/blob/master/docs/windowed-rw.rst) (including the other doc files in the same repository). So how to save the NDVI data to a raster by block?

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 and I use Python 2.7, Gdal 1.10.1, NumPy 1.8.2 and Rasterio 0.26.0 installed from source the way suggested for Linux at [the Rasterio site](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio).

Comment: Can you share some info about the GDAL version, rasterio version, stack trace, operating system, and how you installed rasterio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@geowurster's request on stack trace made me do one more debugging round. The raster's dimensions were 5033x5665 pixels, and I found that it crashes while writing the tile including pixels (0-63)x(4992-5055). I assigned the dimensions to the new raster in the wrong order, so it tried to write outside the raster. I switched the `shape` indexes and it works:

```
with rasterio.open(ndviPath,'w',driver='GTiff', width=src.shape[1], height=src.shape[0], count=1, dtype=np.float32) as dst:
```