# How to use "context" in rasterio?

Tags: python, rasterio

Another `rasterio` follow-up question, after questions on [reading](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/158527/12768) and [writing](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/158853/12768) rasters. I've successfully made and reprojected an output layer, but while trying to use the [`overview`](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/blob/master/rasterio/rio/overview.py) module to build pyramids, I found I don't understand something fundamental: the `ctx` parameter of the function.

```
def overview(ctx, input, build, ls, rebuild, resampling):
```

By a Google search, I found that ctx means "context" and that there's a module named `context` in `click` library used by `rasterio`. I got stuck here: further searching shows "context" only in other contexts. The only useful hints I found here: [`info.py`](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/blob/master/rasterio/rio/info.py) and [`test_rio_info.py`](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/blob/master/tests/test_rio_info.py) files in the `rasterio` repository. I'm not good enough to be able to reverse engineer the `ctx` format expected by the `overview` function from these libraries (not sure whether it is possible).

So I need a good manual explaining contexts as used in `rasterio`, either as an answer or as a link with some summary. How to produce/get them, what exactly do they mean (do they have any use besides passing data into functions?), what are their components (if any) etc.

EDIT: I've found the `Context` class in the `click` library in the `core.py` file on my disk (`/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/click/core.py` on my Ubuntu machine). I didn't manage to explicitely initialize this class object (I didn't understand the params), but after reading [Kersten's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/159185/12768) I think it is not needed while using Rasterio through Python API. The class documentation seems to agree:

> The context is a special internal object that holds state relevant
>   for the script execution at every single level.  It's normally invisible
>   to commands unless they opt-in to getting access to it.
>
> The context is useful as it can pass internal objects around and can
>   control special execution features such as reading data from
>   environment variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `overview` is from rasterios command line interface [`rio`](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/blob/master/rasterio/rio/overview.py).

What you are looking for is the function [`build_overviews`](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/blob/2120a07111998dd18f0911c9cede4be6fe09797a/rasterio/_io.pyx) inside the standard I/O class of rasterio.

How to use that? I have absolutely no idea since I never needed it so far.

Luckily rasterio includes an extensive test suite which also includes one called [`test_overviews.py`](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/blob/1ad1dd4afd143054909899511b0f6d6f59ee56ca/tests/test_overviews.py). If you look at the code inside the test the usage is actually pretty straightforward. When you write a dataset, or open a dataset in read/write mode, you can define the overview levels you want as a list.

```
with rasterio.open('rasterio-test.tif', 'r+') as dst:
    # dst.write() if your dataset has not yet been written to disk
    dst.build_overviews([2,4])
```

On my 4800x4800 pixel test dataset this creates overviews with pyramids of the size 2400x2400 as well as 1200x1200.

```
>> gdalinfo rasterio-test.tif
...
Overviews: 2400x2400, 1200x1200
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. So the Context class is used only for command line functions, where it's handled automatically? Confirm it and I'll gladly accept your answer; +1 anyway.

Comment: Well, as you said `context` and the resulting `ctx.obj` are objects which are parsed from click. See also the [click documentation regarding context objects](http://click.pocoo.org/5/commands/#nested-handling-and-contexts).